# SEO for Gallery-Intensive Web Site

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, local-seo

My 10 years old web site is about niche content(cinema) news gallery. (its a news site; but %90 of pageviews are from galleries)

and i'm getting photographs from news agencies and public relation offices.

i have imagesitemap on my webmastertools page; and has no error.  but, %2-3% of images are indexed by google.

think that, i making news about OSCAR Awards Ceremony. i write 3 paragraph article about it; and add gallery, which i get photos from agency.

my photos cant be unique or first.. of course someone used before me.. but its uniqe or first with turkish content. why am i not in search result in google.com.tr?

and what do you suggest the gallery-intensive web sites as like mine? (adding watermark, or some text detail is not working)

Comment: Since how many years you are doing and maintaining SEO for your website? According to your scenario it is not necessary that your site comes at google.com.tr. Do you focusing on competitive keywords for your site?

Comment: my site is in turkish; and my most important targeted visitors from turkey. i'm focusing on content building; but also, trying to fix my seo status for a couple years.. but actually not focus on competitive keywords so much; because my site is not focusing on 3-5 keyword(its cinema news site; and my position on basic keywords such as cinema, film etc are ok.. i must increase my position on 'terminator 2' film keyword for example.. there can be bilions of keyword combination).. i need whole increase on my detail pages and galleries.

Comment: Okay I understood, But I think you should concentrate on keywords like "news in turkey" , "latest news of turkey" , "latest film in turkey" , "turnkey entertainment news" and a lot more. Because if user search like  "terminator 2'" it will find you site if you have added in article or something regarding that in your site. But it will not help to improve search result.

Comment: in 'terminator 2' keyword, i am at 60th position :) even i have common link such as www.example.com/terminator-2 with galleries, tons of details etc.

Comment: Yes I am telling you same that for famous keyword it do not require to do more effort , it always helps to get you ranking. But main thing is competitive and important keywords related to your site.

Comment: you are welcome.Well I am not expert in SEO , I have suggested you everything as per my SEO experience of 4 years.